# Error #1063 when migrating project from flex 3.5 to 3.6A

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Im getting the following error when trying to run my application:
**VerifyError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on mx.core::RSLItem(). Expected 1, got 3.**

The original application was built with Flash Builder 4 (SDK 3.5), and imported in Flash Builder 4.6 (using SDK 3.6A).

The error is displayed only when the framework linkage type is set to RSL, when using the framework linkage "Merged into code", the application runs fine. But we need to use RSL as the application is quite large.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: this is basically an error caused by argument mismatch, some where in your code your calling a function with extra arguments

Comment: thanks for your reply, but im not calling this function anywhere in my code. The error is on flex core files (mx.core::RSLItem()). Im getting the error when i use framework linkage "RSL" in my project's properties. When i change that to "Merged into code" the error disappears, but we need to use RSL as framework linkage for the application.

Answer (score 0):

you are loading wrong rsl's. (probably swz files) (about rsl: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/rsl_09.html)
the simplest way to solve that is to create a new project, and only import the code you've written.

Comment: hi.. i did as you suggested, created a new project then imported only the code i've written, but i'm still getting the following error: VerifyError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on mx.core::RSLItem(). Expected 1, got 3.

 at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::initialize()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:1949]
 at mx.managers::SystemManager/initHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:3064]

Comment: The only way to avoid this error is to set the framework linkage as 'Merged into code', but this results to a bigger SWF... The error is displayed when the framework linkage is set to "RSL"... any idea?

Comment: do you need the RSL-s? on your project propeties you can turn off some options, that could help. i don't know which ones (i'm not near a FB right now)..